# How to add control of  other page in Iframe which is on first page

Tags: asp.net

I m using asp.net 4.0.
In My first page i have html Iframe Having id ="ControlFrame" .
I want to dyanamically fill this frame on button click . My problem is that i want to know that how to add panel of  second page in this iframe which is on first page. 
I want to add this dyanamically.

Plz give me the best solution
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See the aspx section,

```
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnID" runat="server" 
                onclick="lnkBtnID_Click">
               </asp:LinkButton>
     <iframe  id="iframeID" runat="server" height="500px" width="500px"></iframe>
```

In aspx.cs section within the lnkBtnID_Click event do the following code to load your page,

```
     protected void lnkBtnID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        iframeID.Attributes.Add("src", "page2.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: See i want to add controls of other page like panel but dont want to add the wholepage in that frame... So plz give me the best solution for it ... Thnx

Comment: It is not possible to load a particular control inside a page using iframe. Instead you should place this panel in a different page and load that page fully as shown above.

Comment: thnx for reply... but i think there may be solution .